# Restore data from Postgres data files

Tags: postgresql

Got system with Postgres broken (a RAID is the reason) , without any backups.

Trying to put data to another comptuter with Postgres (and make however backup).

But always when I set up data directory and run postgres I've got message

```
GET FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2012-08-15 19:58:38 GET DETAIL:  The database cluster was initialized with BLCKSZ 16777216, but the server was compiled with BLCKSZ 8192.
2012-08-15 19:58:38 GET HINT:  It looks like you need to recompile or initdb.
```

It's very strange number 16777216(2 to power 24 - to big).

However I can't reset default value 8192 when compiling (playing with --with-blocksize= take no effect; BLCKSZ - I can't find it in headers files)

).

Any way to extract data ?

**This is environment and circumstances:**

harddrive: RAID 1 with 3 SAS disks in array

OS: ubuntu 10.04.04 amd64

Postgres: 9.1 (by apt-get (we change repository links to higher version of Ubuntu))

the system become broken - after some time got

> AAC: Host Adapter BLINK LED 0x56
>   AACO: Adapter kernel panic'd 56

(filesystem or hardware error)

Somehow we got data directory. pg_conroldata shown:

pg_control version number:                903
Catalog version number:                    201105231
Database system identifier:                5714530593695276911
Database cluster state:                      shut down
pg_control last modified:                    Tue 15 Aug 2012 11:50:50
Latest checkpoint location:                1B595668/2000020
Prior checkpoint location:                   0/0
Latest checkpoint's REDO location:     1B595668/2000020
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:         1
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:                0/4057946
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:              40960
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:   1
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:   0
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID:            670
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID's DB:    1344846103
Latest checkpoint's oldestActiveXID:  0
Time of latest checkpoint:                  Tue 15 Aug 2012 11:50:50
Minimum recovery ending location:    0/0
Backup start location:                         0/0
Current wal_level setting:                     minimal
Current max_connections setting:      100
Current max_prepared_xacts setting:0
Current max_locks_per_xact setting:   64
Maximum data alignment:                  8
Database block size:                              16777216
Blocks per segment of large relation:131072
WAL block size:                                 8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                  16777216
Maximum length of identifiers:             64
Maximum columns in an index:          2387576020
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:          0
Date/time type storage:                         floating-point numbers
Float4 argument passing:                       by reference
Float8 argument passing:                      by reference

First I effort to up DB in Ubuntu servers (harddisk - simple serial 2, Ubuntu 10.04 i386, Postgres 9.1) and got the same exception above (with BLCKSZ).

That's why I deployed Ubuntu 10.04 amd64 with english Postgres 9.1 (because got '**?**' instead of russian symbols in error logs in previous step) in virtual machine
Got the same exception (with BLCKSZ).

Ather that have removed apt-get postgres version and compiled it as described at docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/installation.html.
Playing with`configure --with-blocksize=BLOCKSIZE` had take no effect - got the same error

### Sorry, for the post.

The pg_contol was broken by some manipulations with.

Sow, the cluster was succeful restored by pg_resetxlog with initial data.

Comment: What does 'put data to another computer' exactly mean in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blocksize of 16Mb would be really weird, and since these two values also look completely bogus:

> ```
> Maximum columns in an index:       2387576020
> Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:     0
> ```

...you might want to question the integrity of this data before spending time on compiling postgres with a non-standard block size.

If you look at the sizes of files corresponding to relations, are they multiple of 16Mb or 8Kb?
If the database have some gigabytes tables, what appears to be the cut-off size on disk (the size above which postgres split the data into several files)? This should be equal to `data block size`*`Blocks per segment of large relation`. On a default install, it's 1Gb.

Comment: You right! data settings looks like default! - Sow the pg_control was broken. I get working cluster by copying (pg_control).  But there is only one DataBase from the list and only functions and custom types are available there. Any way to resolve, or it should be another question ?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/kernel-resources.html) for details on configuring kernel resources. Perhaps the default/current settings for this new OS won't allow the postmaster to start.

[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-preset.html) are details on the meaning and context of the BLCKSZ parameter. Was the system that failed running a 64bit build of PostgreSQL and the new system is a 32bit build? If possible, attempting to obtain version information on the failed system's PostgreSQL could shed light on the problem. Let us know what version, build, and OS were used. Was is a custom build?